# Probability of $P\bigl(X+Y<\frac{1}{2}\bigr)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ & $Y$ be two continuous random variables with the joint probability density

$$f(x,y)=2 ,0<x+y<1,x>0,y>0$$
$$f(x,y)=0,elsewhere$$

Find the value of $P\left(X+Y<\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$.

Comment: Draw a picture in the $xy$ plane.

Comment: What have you tried and where do you need help? This is a double integral...I assume you're trouble is with the bounds of integration?

Comment: Yes...It is trouble to me only the bound of the integrations..I want to know the bounds & how we compute it particularly for this problem..

Comment: @ Felix Martin has given good advice then. Try drawing this in the xy-plane. Once you've drawn a picture and determined the area you're using, you will see that your inner integral will have bounds than include a variable of the same kind as the outer integral.

Comment: I drew the picture. The limits are $0<x<\dfrac{1}{2}$ & $0<y<\dfrac{1}{2} -x$. I think it was wrong because it contradics the answer. So I want to know the limits if I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounds on the double integral are:

$$
\mathbb P(X+Y\leq 1/2) = \int_0^{1/2}\int_0^{1/2-x} 2 \operatorname d y \operatorname d x
$$

**Alternatively:**  The density function is uniformly distribution over the triangle below $X+Y=1$ and in the first quadrant.  The favoured event we seek consists of the triangle below $X+Y=1/2$ and in the first quadrant.  What fraction of the former is the later?